# Use comparison operator with time field in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column time in my Excel sheet which has values like

> 5:20PM
>   7:00PM
>   3:30AM
>   ...etc

Now I wanted to use a `CountIf` function to count those cells whose time does not come under the range 6am to 5pm. Basically any 'Time' which is either less than 6am and greater than 5Pm should be counted.
However, I could not make it work, is there a function that I can use in this scenario?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to show what you tried and how it didn't work?

Comment: Are the values actually Times, or only strings that look like times?

Comment: @chrisneilsen the values are actually times and not strings

Comment: @karan ok, then Adam's answer will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is `TIME(hour, minute, second)`.

Make sure the Time column is of Excel format Time. Then your CountIf criteria can be `">"&TIME(19,0,0)`for greater than 5:00PM or `"<"&TIME(6,0,0)` for less than 6:00AM.

You also want an or criteria overall. So you can add two CountIf functions together, one for each criteria, or make a dummy column and sum over that.

```
=COUNTIFS(datarange,">"&TIME(17,0,0))+COUNTIFS(datarange,"<"&TIME(6,0,0))
```